# adding some HTML in admin panel form magento

Tags: forms, magento, panel, admin

In `app/code/local/namspace/module/Block/Adminhtml/module/Edit/Tab/Form.php` we basically add all the fields. Is there anyway to add any HTML to this form e.g. some form instructions for filling the form.

I have this layout under **app/code/local/namspace/module/Block/**

```
Block
|
|____Adminhtml
    |
    |____ Module
        |
        |__Edit
        |   |__Form.php
        |   |__Tabs.php
        |   |
        |   |__Tab
        |       |___Form.php
        |
        |__Edit.php
```

Thanks

Comment: +1 for the nice, thoughtful graphic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really understand the question.  Are you trying to add new fields into the admin?  If so, that can be done with XML.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations#source_model

"comment is useful for providing extra descriptions or information. Wrap it’s text in a CDATA tag if you want to use HTML, any HTML is allowed but the most common use is to create highlight spans with a “notice” or “warning” class."

If my response is way off, please update your question with some more information, as I'm still not real sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks for your input. I am neither trying to add any field nor trying any comments to fields. I am trying to add some instruction for form filling & they are not just validation or errors messages. So far I am not able to find any suitable way/ I appreciate u actually took some time & efforts to look into my problem

Comment: @SAM: Maybe I'm not understanding correctly, but wouldn't a comment work for what you need?  I think the comment actually displays in the admin to give the user more information about the field.  I think you could put the instructions in there.

Comment: yeah that can work. Anyway requirement changed. Thanks for you help